# How to avoid "ValueError: Separator is not found, and chunk exceed the limit"

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a server that uses asyncio in the following way:

```
proc = await asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec(
    command,
    stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=asyncio.subprocess.STDOUT)

async for line in proc.stdout:
    line = line.decode('utf-8').strip()
    print(line)
```

The problem is, if `proc.stdout` contains a line that is too long, I get in line of the `for` statement the error:

```
ValueError: Separator is not found, and chunk exceed the limit
```

How can I detect such long lines in order to avoid this error in advance?

Comment: I don't know how to check for long lines in advance, but depending on the length of the lines you expect, you could increase the buffer size with the `limit` argument of the `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` function.

Comment: The use of `asyncio.StreamReader.read()` or `asyncio.StreamReader.readexactly()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio-streams allows the consumption of arbitrary streams. This, however, requires some additional logic elsewhere in the code to decide where lines start/end and putting them together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.create_subprocess_exec) says:

> The `limit` argument sets the buffer limit for `StreamReader` wrappers for
>   `Process.stdout` and `Process.stderr` (if `subprocess.PIPE` is passed to
>   stdout and stderr arguments).

Seems to be what we need.

Default limit [seems to be](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fd512d76456b65c529a5bc58d8cfe73e4a10de7a/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#L21) 64 KiB, you can try something higher:

```
proc = await asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec(
    command,
    limit = 1024 * 128,  # 128 KiB
    stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=asyncio.subprocess.STDOUT)
```

**Upd:**

> I just want to truncate/ignore lines that are too long. Is this
>   possible?

You can suppress errors on long lines and continue afterwards. Following code (tested on Windows) shows the idea:

```
import asyncio


async def main():
    proc = await asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec(
        *[
            'wget', 
            '--help'
        ],
        limit = 20,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, 
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.STDOUT)

    while True:
        try:
            async for line in proc.stdout:
                line = line.decode('utf-8').strip()
                print(line)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            break


loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: I do not want something higher - I just want to truncate/ignore lines that are too long. Is this possible?